# How to vertically align with 100% width?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel

How to accomplish vertical alignment -- JPanels on top of each other with 100% width size?

I want something like this but am unclear how to go about it.

[image: What I Want]

Comment: You could use try using the `VerticalLayout` from [SwingLabs SwingX library](https://java.net/projects/swingx/downloads/directory/releases)

Comment: I ll take a look at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a [BoxLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html) LayoutManager should help you to align vertically (see Y_AXIS) .

Comment: Doesn't satisfy 100% width. BoxLayout works with preferred size if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way you can use `BorderLayout` for that:

```
frame = new JFrame();
frame.setBounds(100, 100, 495, 311);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
frame.getContentPane().add(jPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: And when I add more jPanels to the center it will align vertically?

Comment: If you have more Panels, then it is good to use `FormLayout` which the most powerful layout for GUI